# Why does an ActiveRecord select query response contain an 'id' column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

A query like this:

`User.where(username:'myuser').select(:created_at).first.to_json`

Returns JSON like this:
`{\"created_at\":\"2014-03-01 18:03:00\",\"id\":null}`

Why is there an "id" field in the generated JSON? Is there an easy way to get rid of it? I don't want to use :pluck because I need the field labels in the returned data structure.

Comment: just tried this in the console and I only get the created_at part as expected.  can you check if you have a default scope defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might have been a change in Rails 4 where a query like `User.where(username:'myuser').select(:created_at).first` will include the `id` value even though it wasn't a part of the select.  You can exclude it with:

```
User.where(username:'myuser').select(:created_at).first.to_json(except: :id)
```

Comment: Thanks for the except: suggestion.